# Makefile for unit tests using it's counter-part in another directory

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have a structure like this:

```
src/a/foo.cpp
src/b/bar.cpp
src/main.cpp
tests/a/test_foo.cpp
tests/b/test_bar.cpp
tests/test_all.cpp
```

I'd really like a Makefile to build the sources and build the tests. For the sources, I have this setup:

```
src = $(shell find src -name "*.cpp")
objs = $(src:.c=.o)
bin = stuff

$(bin): $(objs)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

For the tests, I would like to have a similar simplistic structure where each test would take build it's counter-part in `src` and itself as well.

So, for `test_foo`, I'd like a task like this:

```
clang++ -o test_foo tests/test_foo.cpp src/foo.cpp
```

Also, do you think it's a good idea to have a separate `Makefile` for tests and another one for the binary?

Many thanks

Comment: Why would you make a separate makefile?  A single makefile can do it all.  If you created multiple makefiles you'd just end up duplicating a lot of stuff.

Comment: A single Makefile works just as good. How would the `test` task look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some build the test stuff to your makefile.  Maybe something like:

```
testsrcs := $(wildcard tests/test_*.cpp)
testbins := $(testsrcs:tests/%.cpp=%)

tests: $(testbins)

$(testbins): test_% : tests/test_%.cpp src/%.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist! Is there an easy solution for including the same structure but for .cpp files that are in subdirectories. For example `src/foo/foo_a.cpp` and a test in `tests/foo/test_foo_a.cpp`? I edited the structure above for clarity

Comment: No, that's not so easy because the `%` cannot match the same string in all cases.  If you want to do that you'll have to create a set of rules, one for each directory, using a more advanced configuration relying on `eval` etc.

Comment: Understood. When I ran the above, I got this: `No rule to make target `tests/test_%.cpp' `. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I guess it should be `$(testsrcs:tests/%.cpp=%)`  Will fix